# When writing a test for a service class, throws a NullPointerException exception due to the repository object used in the service class

Tags: java, spring, testing, service, mockito

I am trying to test a service method. The method looks like this:

```
@Component
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    @Autowired
    public TaskRepository taskRepository;

    //tested method
    @Override
    public boolean addTask(Task task) {

        if (taskNameIsNull(task) || taskNameAndDescriptionIsNull(task)) {
            return false;
        }

        taskRepository.save(task);
        return true;
    }

    //other code

}
```

So, I write test for method addTask using JUnit5 and mockito:

```
class TaskServiceImplTest {

    private TaskServiceImpl taskService = new TaskServiceImpl();

    @Mock
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Test
    void addTaskTest(){
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setName("SomeName");
        task.setDescription("SomeDescription");
        assertEquals(true, taskService.addTask(task));
    }
```

And when I start test method addTaskTest I get NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spring_project.nadia.tasks_timer.service.TaskServiceImplTest.addTask(TaskServiceImplTest.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

As far as I understand, the NullPointerException is thrown because of the TaskRepository class object. I thing so because other tests of the addTask method test cases when this method returns false passed.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. This **doesn't a Spring Boot** application, but just Spring Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a mock repository, but not injected into your service. As you wrote, other tests of the `addTask` method passed when this method returns `false`, because in this case your repo isn't invoked.

Also add one of the annotations above the test-class depending on which version of JUnit you are using:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  // for JUnit4 
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)  // for JUnit5
class TaskServiceImplTest {
  
    @InjectMocks // inject mocks into class under test
    private TaskServiceImpl taskService;

    @Mock
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Test
    void addTaskTest(){
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setName("SomeName");
        task.setDescription("SomeDescription");
        assertTrue(taskService.addTask(task));
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly correct. You need to inject a taskRepository mock into the taskService class under test.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very relevant to the question, but here's advice...
Please, prefer [constructor injection](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring) instead of field injection, it's a good practice.

```
@Component
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    public final TaskRepository taskRepository;

    public TaskServiceImpl(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
        this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }
}
```

Then you can just:

```
class TaskServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    @InjectMocks 
    private TaskServiceImpl taskService
}
```

Or

```
class TaskServiceImplTest {

    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    private TaskServiceImpl taskService

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        taskRepository = mock(TaskRepository.class);
        taskService = new TaskServiceImpl(taskRepository);
    }
}
```